# Obtener variables del for y despues insertarlas a una base de datos en un rest

Tags: php7, rest

Este es mi codigo, necesito saber como recupero las variables que estoy mostrando en el for, para poderlas insertar en mi base de datos

```
 if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
    {
        $array = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
        print_r($array);
        echo "<br>";
        for( $i=0; $i<count( $array ); $i++ ){
        echo $array[$i]["nombre_fruta"]."<br>";
        echo $array[$i]["cantidad"]."<br>";
        }
}
```

Comment: el siguiente codigo es para insertar, pero no me funciona     $input = $_POST;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO estacion_agrometeorologica
          (idant, temperatura, pp, hr, pr, rad.g, vv, dv, Id_Punto)
          VALUES
          (:idant, :temperatura, :, :, :, :, :, :,:)";
    $statement = $dbConn->prepare($sql);
    bindAllValues($statement, $input);
    $statement->execute();
    $postId = $dbConn->lastInsertId();
    if($postId)
    {
      $input['id'] = $postId;
      header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
      echo json_encode($input);
      exit();
   }

Comment: la informacion que recibo en json_decode, la envio desde un json